In proof of Primary decomposition for a module over principal ideal domain
I am reading proof of Primary docomposition for module over PID ( Proposition (5.4.10) in the Antoine Chambert-Lori, (Mostly) Commutative Algebra ) and two qeustions arise.
Let $A$ be a principal ideal domain and let $M$ be an A-module. For every irreducible element $p\in A$, the set $M(p)$ of all $m\in M$ for which there exists an integer $n \ge 0$ with $p^{n}m=0$ is a submodule on $M$, called the $p$-primary component of $M$.
Now we fix a set $\mathcal{P}$ of irreducible elements in $A$ such that any irreducible element of $A$ is equal to the product of unit by a unique element of $\mathcal{P}$. In particular, when $p$ varies in $\mathcal{P}$, the ideals $(p)$ are maiximal and pairwise distinct.
Now let me state the Primary decomposition and propose its proof.

Proposition (5.4.10) ( Primary decomposition ) Let $A$ be a principal ideal domain, let $M$ be an $A$-module. Then the torsion submodule of $M$ decomposes as the direct sum $T(M)= \bigoplus_{p\in \mathcal{P}}M(p)$.



Q. First, I don't know what the first underlined statement in the proof does exactly means. What is definition of  "~are in direct sum "? And why the statement "$m_p=0$ for every $p\in \mathcal{P}$" imlies that $M(p)$ 's are in direct sum?
And, second, why did the author proves the first underlined statement? If the underlined statement is not proved, then full proof of the Proposition becomes incomplete? If so, why?

When one says that a module $M$ is direct sum of $M_i$ for $i \in \Lambda$ one means that $M$ is isomorphic to the following submodule of $\prod_{i \in \Lambda} M_i$ $$ \{ (m_i)_{i \in \Lambda} \mid m_i = 0 \text{ for all but finitely many } i \} $$
In practice if all of them are submodules of a bigger module one just takes finite sums from those $M_i$'s, together with the condition that they have no common intersection. Try to prove it is equivalent with what is said in the notes.

O.K. Therefore, you mean that the author is claming that the 'internal' direct sum (C.f. Hungerford's Algebra, Chapter IV, Theorem 1.15 ) $\bigoplus_{p \in \mathcal{P}}M(p)$ is 'well-defined' ?

yes @Plantation

Thank you ~~~~~
